# Undefined Variable

Tags: php, mysql, ip

so I been getting this issue on my login page where its unable to find a variable I set but I have made sure its on the database. I have compared it with the databse and it all seems to match so I am not sure why im getting this error. Please find details below. Thank you for your help :)

> Error : Notice: Undefined variable: ID in
>   /home/scylla97/public_html/login.php on line 89

Code :

```
            $SQLCheckLogin = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username AND `password` = :password");
        $SQLCheckLogin -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => SHA1($password)));
        $countLogin = $SQLCheckLogin -> fetchColumn(0);
        if ($countLogin == 1)
        {
            $SQLGetInfo = $odb -> prepare("SELECT `access`, `username`, `ID`, `rank` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username AND `password` = :password");
            $SQLGetInfo -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => SHA1($password)));
            $userInfo = $SQLGetInfo -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if ($userInfo['access'] == 0)
            {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $userInfo['username'];
                $_SESSION['ID'] = $userInfo['ID'];
                {
                    $ip = getRealIpAddr();
                    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                    {
                        $SQL = $odb -> prepare('INSERT INTO `logs` VALUES(:id ,:username, :loggedip, UNIX_TIMESTAMP())');
                        $SQL -> execute(array(':loggedip' => $ip, ':username' => $username, ':id' => $id));
                        echo '<div class="nNote nSuccess hideit"><p><font color=\'white\'><strong>SUCCESS: </strong>Login Successful. Redirecting....</font></p></div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=index.php">';
                        die();
```

Line 89 is :

```
$SQL -> execute(array(':loggedip' => $ip, ':username' => $username, ':id' => $id));
```

Database of Logs : 
[image: Its the logs table on phpmyadmin]

I apologies in advanced if this is a stupid question and really easy to fix but I have spent the last few hours looking at it and playing around with it but still no fix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: is this all your code?

Comment: at the moment $id` is undefined that is true, you just used it without defining it

Comment: change ':id' => $id to ':id' => $_SESSION['ID']

Comment: No but it is most of it, will it help if I post it all ? Just the rest of it works fine, its only that section for that issue.

Comment: @user3657631 you have an answer below

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Thank you

Comment: @Raman Thank you very much for the fix as well :)

Comment: SHA1 is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you miss your $id value and hope your `$username` already you get so first assign value using $id like

```
$id = $userInfo['ID'];
```

so add this line

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $userInfo['username'];
$_SESSION['ID'] = $userInfo['ID'];
$id = $userInfo['ID'];
```

so your query

```
 $SQL -> execute(array(':loggedip' => $ip, ':username' => $username, ':id' => $id));
```

or update your query

```
$SQL -> execute(array(':loggedip' => $ip, ':username' => $username, ':id' => $_SESSION['ID']));
```

hope it will help you